# combination columns in validationRule

Tags: validation, adonis.js

I'm New in Adonis.js,I Have user-migration such as this:

```
  table.enu('type', ['client','admin','super_admin']),
  table.string('mobile', 80).notNullable().unique();
```

Now,I Want to check `mobile + type` be unique for all users in validation,While I just can check mobile unique with this code:

```
mobile : 'required|string|unique:users,mobile',
```

How I can so this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created something like that, using extending validator:

```
async unique_combinationFn(data, field, message, args, get) { // eslint-disable-line
const Database = use('Database');
const value = get(data, field);
if (!value) {
  return;
}
const [table, ...columns] = args;

const multipleClauses = columns.reduce(
  (oldObject, column) => ({
    ...oldObject,
    [column]: data[column],
  }),
  {}
);

const where = { ...multipleClauses, [field]: value };

const row = data.id
  ? await Database.table(table)
      .where(where)
      .whereNot('id', data.id)
      .first()
  : await Database.table(table)
      .where(where)
      .first();
if (row) {
  throw message;
}
```

}

and to use:

```
code: [rule('required'), rule('unique_combination', ['users', 'company_id'])],
```

you can find more in doc in this link:

[Extending Validator](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/validator#_extending_validator)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with Adonis.js's own validator. You should write your own validation method for this kind use case.

Check the reply about this from Adonisjs's founder here: https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/several-unique-fields/1430/3